# Is there a plugin for bar charts where I can switch the output with a slider?

Tags: jquery

What I basically want to do is to create a chart with two horizontal bar charts. Each bar represents a property in %, e.g. "uses smart phones" and the other "uses normal cellphones".
Then, I want to have some sort of slider that I can move, and that changes the output of the bar chart according to the e.g. the year. So the slider would basically be another axis that the user can manipulate.
So I am asking myself if there is a jQuery plugin etc. that does this natively, or if I have to hook two things together: a slider that loads a different bar chart depending on the position / value.

Comment: here is a list of jquery charts, but not sure about the slider thing... http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/top-jquery-chart-libraries-interactive-charts/